# CodeIgniter validación exige campo requerido aún cuando se puso

Tags: php, codeigniter, validación

Uso php con Codeigniter, tengo los campos nombre apellido y fecha en un formulario, aún cuando los ingreso, me sale el mensaje: El campo es obligatorio.

cliente.php

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class cliente extends CI_Controller{
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->database();
            //llamo o incluyo el modelo
            $this->load->model("main_model");

        }

        function mostrarInicio(){
            $this->load->view("inicio");
            $query = $this->db->get('tbl_cliente');
            var_dump($query->result());
        }

        function mostrarDatos(){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('texDocumentoDeIdentidad', 'Documento de identidad', 'trim|required|max_length[12]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('texPassword', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('texNombre', 'Nombre', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('texApellido', 'Apellido', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('texDireccion', 'Dirección', 'trim|min_length[10]|max_length[30]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('texTelefono', 'Teléfono', 'trim|min_length[7]|max_length[12]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('texFechaIngreso', 'Fecha de ingreso', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[12]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('texEstado', 'Estado', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[16]');

            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                $this->load->view('formulario_cliente');
            }
            else{

                $datos=array(
                    'documentoDeIdentidad' => $this->input->post('texDocumentoDeIdentidad'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('texPassword'),
                    'nombre' => $this->input->post('texNombre'),
                    'apellido' => $this->input->post('texApellido'),
                    'direccion' => $this->input->post('texDireccion'),
                    'telefono' => $this->input->post('texTelefono'),
                    'fechaIngreso' => $this->input->post('texFechaIngreso'),
                    'estado' => $this->input->post('texEstado')                 
                );
                $this->load->view("formulario_cliente", $datos);
            }
        } //mostrarDatos
```

formulario_cliente.php

```
<div id="error">
        <?php 
            echo validation_errors();
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        echo form_open('cliente/mostrarDatos');
    ?>

    <div id="contact">  
        <h1 align='center'>Cliente</h2> 
    <form > 
        <fieldset>
            <label for="texDocumentoDeIdentidad">Documento de identidad </label>
            <input type="text" name="texDocumentoDeIdentidad" id="texDocumentoDeIdentidad" value="<?php echo set_value('texDocumentoDeIdentidad', '');?>"/> 
            <br>
            <label for="texDocumentoDeIdentidad">Password </label>
            <input type="text" name="texPassword" id="texPassword" />
            <br>
            <label for="texNombres">Nombres </label>
            <input type="text" name="texNombres" id="texNombres" value="<?php echo set_value('texNombres', '');?>"/>
            <br>
            <label for="texApellidos">Apellidos </label>
            <input type="text" name="texApellidos" id="texApellidos" value="<?php echo set_value('texApellidos', '');?>"/>
            <br>
            <label for="texDireccion">Dirección </label>
            <input type="text" name="texDireccion" id="texDireccion" value="<?php echo set_value('texDireccion', '');?>"/>
            <br>
            <label for="texTelefono">Teléfono </label>
            <input type="text" name="texTelefono" id="texTelefono" value="<?php echo set_value('texTelefono', '');?>"/>
            <br>
            <label for="texFechaDeIngreso">Fecha de ingreso </label>
            <input type="text" name="texFechaDeIngreso" id="texFechaDeIngreso" value="<?php echo set_value('texFechaDeIngreso', '');?>"/>
            <br>
            <label for="texEstado">Estado </label>
            <input type="text" name="texEstado" id="texEstado" value="<?php echo set_value('texEstado', '');?>"/>
            <br>

            <div id="botones">
                <input type="submit" name="buscarCliente" value="Buscar Cliente" />
                <input type="button" name="limpiar" value="Limpiar" />  
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>

    <?php
        echo form_close();
    ?>

    <br>    
    <div id="resultado">
        <?php
            if(!empty($documentoDeIdentidad) && !empty($password) && !empty($nombre) && !empty($apellido) && !empty($fechaIngreso) && !empty($estado)){

                echo "Documento de identidad: $documentoDeIdentidad<br>";
                echo "Password: $password<br>";
                echo "Nombre: $nombre<br>";
                echo "Apellido: $apellido<br>";
                echo "Dirección: $direccion<br>";
                echo "Teléfono: $telefono<br>";
                echo "Fecha de ingreso: $fechaIngreso<br>";
                echo "Estado: $estado<br>";             
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en una pequeña diferencia en los nombres de los campos; por ejemplo era texFechaDeIngreso en lugar de texFechaIngreso... lo mismo pasaba con nombre y apellido.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza notaciones hungaras así no tienes confusiones cuando estés llamando nuevamente los campos de los textos ejemplo:

txtCampoTexto

dtCampoFecha

etc.

asi es mas facil identificarlos.

Cuando tengas mas experiencia colocalos en Ingles asi trabajas con normas standard

Espero haberte ayudado.

DTB.